# Null response from XMLHttpRequest in OS X Javascript Widget

Tags: javascript, macos, null, xmlhttprequest, widget

I want to develop a little os x widget which fetches data from an xml source and then displays the results. 
My problem is I never used javascript XMLHttpRequest before and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

To start my project I want to create a simple script which returns the response header and alert it. 
I've tried lot's of different things I found on the web and I know it can't be that difficult.

But whatever I try I get a '**null**' response. I even tried to get the content directly but with no luck.

I once heared that cross domain requests don't work but I'm not sure if this info is up to date. And if it's up to date then how can I make a request to a server using javascript when the javascript runs local, on my Mac in a widget ??

Here's my code, maybe someone can show me what I'm doing wrong.

```
<html>
<title>This is a test</title>
<body>
This is a simple test.
    <p class="example"><a href="#" onclick="init();return false;">Try this.</a></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function init()
    {   
        xmlhttprequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttprequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttprequest.readyState == 4) {
            alert(xmlhttprequest.getAllResponseHeaders());
            }
        }               
    var url = "http://stinfwww.informatik.uni-leipzig.de" ;
    xmlhttprequest.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttprequest.send(null);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone got any suggestion I would really appreciate this. Or if you have any good resources (esp. on Javascript Widget Development) on this topic please let me know.

Thanks indeed

Comment: I found out that os x widgets are not bound to the usual security constraints of a browser. You can request anything from anywhere. So developing widgets with a normal browser doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers restrict cross-domain requests for security purposes. So Javascript at http://localhost can’t retrieve data from a remote API

Also read this http://htmltimes.com/cross-domain-javascript-xmlhttprequest-restriction.php

Hope that help's